# Calculate Christoffel symbols of the second kind from the first kind

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemmanian manifold. If a connection $\nabla$ is defined in a way such that $\Gamma_{ij,k}$ is given for all $i,j$ and $k$, how do we find $\Gamma_{ij}^k$? $\nabla$ is not necessarily Levi Civita connection here so we can't use $\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{1}{2} g^{kl}(\partial_i g_{jl} + \partial_j g_{il} - \partial_l g_{ij}) $.

Thanks

Comment: Since you're not talking about the L-C connection, it would be helpful to include your definitions of $\Gamma_{ij,k}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ just to be sure. Assuming they're related by the metric as usual, the answer should either be to contract with the metric or its inverse.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis There was some misunderstanding on the paper. The author gave the definition of a flat connection (not Levi-Civita) on the normal distribution family, which is defined by $\Gamma_{ij,k}$. Then he gave the formula for $\Gamma_{ij}^k$, which should be of Levi-Civita connection but he didn't specify. Anyway I don't have any other questions and thanks for your help.